ros2_control_node errors after ROS2 Rolling update
I have ROS2 Rolling installed last year on one laptop and my launch file just works fine there.
But I have newly installed ROS2 Rolling on other laptop and same launch file doesn't work there.
My launch file:
import os

import moveit_configs_utils.launches
from ament_index_python.packages import get_package_share_directory
from launch import LaunchDescription
from launch.actions import (DeclareLaunchArgument, IncludeLaunchDescription, RegisterEventHandler)
from launch.event_handlers import OnProcessExit
from launch.launch_description_sources import PythonLaunchDescriptionSource
from launch.substitutions import LaunchConfiguration
from launch_ros.actions import Node
from moveit_configs_utils import MoveItConfigsBuilder
import yaml

from launch.actions import ExecuteProcess, IncludeLaunchDescription, RegisterEventHandler, DeclareLaunchArgument,Shutdown

def load_yaml(package_name, file_path):
        package_path = get_package_share_directory(package_name)
        absolute_file_path = os.path.join(package_path, file_path)
        try:
            with open(absolute_file_path, 'r') as file:
                return yaml.safe_load(file)
        except EnvironmentError:
            return None
        
def generate_launch_description():

    # Load paremeters for moveit_config
    moveit_config = (
        MoveItConfigsBuilder(
            robot_name="rm_robot", package_name="rm75_6f"
        )
        .planning_scene_monitor(publish_robot_description=True) # не влияет на результаты загрузки
        .robot_description(file_path="config/rm_robot.urdf.xacro")
        .trajectory_execution(file_path="config/moveit_controllers.yaml")
        .planning_scene_monitor(publish_robot_description=True, publish_robot_description_semantic=True)
        .planning_pipelines(pipelines=["ompl"])
        .joint_limits(file_path="config/joint_limits.yaml")
        # .pilz_cartesian_limits(file_path="config/pilz_cartesian_limits.yaml")
        # .moveit_cpp(file_path="config/moveit_cpp.yaml")
        .to_moveit_configs()
    )

    moveit_config_dict = moveit_config.to_dict()

    # Start the actual move_group node/action server
    run_move_group_node = Node(
        package="moveit_ros_move_group",
        executable="move_group",
        output="screen",
        parameters=[moveit_config_dict],
    )

    rsp_node = Node(
        package="robot_state_publisher",
        executable="robot_state_publisher",
        respawn=True,
        output="screen",
        parameters=[moveit_config_dict],
    )

    # ros2_control using FakeSystem as hardware
    ros2_controllers_path = os.path.join(
        get_package_share_directory("rm75_6f"),
        "config",
        "ros2_controllers.yaml",
    )

    ros2_control_node = Node(
        package="controller_manager",
        executable="ros2_control_node",
        parameters=[
            moveit_config.robot_description, 
            ros2_controllers_path],
        output="both",
    )

    # Load controllers
    load_controllers = []
    for controller in [
        "robot_arm_controller",
        "joint_state_controller",
    ]:
        load_controllers += [
            ExecuteProcess(
                cmd=["ros2 run controller_manager spawner {}".format(controller)],
                shell=True,
                output="screen",
            )
        ]

    return LaunchDescription(
        [   
            ros2_control_node,
            rsp_node,
            # moveit_configs_utils.launches.generate_rsp_launch(moveit_config),
            moveit_configs_utils.launches.generate_static_virtual_joint_tfs_launch(moveit_config),
            moveit_configs_utils.launches.generate_moveit_rviz_launch(moveit_config),
            # moveit_configs_utils.launches.generate_move_group_launch(moveit_config),
            run_move_group_node,
        ] + load_controllers
    )

Error:
robot@robot:~$ ros2 launch rm75_6f rm_robot.launch.py
[INFO] [launch]: All log files can be found below /home/robot/.ros/log/2024-04-22-16-34-10-890785-robot-54642
[INFO] [launch]: Default logging verbosity is set to INFO
Using load_yaml() directly is deprecated. Use xacro.load_yaml() instead.
[INFO] [ros2_control_node-1]: process started with pid [54645]
[INFO] [robot_state_publisher-2]: process started with pid [54647]
[INFO] [static_transform_publisher-3]: process started with pid [54649]
[INFO] [rviz2-4]: process started with pid [54651]
[INFO] [move_group-5]: process started with pid [54653]
[INFO] [ros2 run controller_manager spawner robot_arm_controller-6]: process started with pid [54655]
[INFO] [ros2 run controller_manager spawner joint_state_controller-7]: process started with pid [54657]
[ros2_control_node-1] [WARN] [1713792851.173091822] [controller_manager]: [Deprecated] Passing the robot description parameter directly to the control_manager node is deprecated. Use '~/robot_description' topic from 'robot_state_publisher' instead.
[ros2_control_node-1] [INFO] [1713792851.173424882] [resource_manager]: Loading hardware 'GenericSystem' 
[ros2_control_node-1] terminate called after throwing an instance of 'pluginlib::LibraryLoadException'
[ros2_control_node-1]   what():  According to the loaded plugin descriptions the class fake_components/GenericSystem with base class type hardware_interface::SystemInterface does not exist. Declared types are  mock_components/GenericSystem test_hardware_components/TestSystemCommandModes test_hardware_components/TestTwoJointSystem
[ros2_control_node-1] Stack trace (most recent call last):
[ros2_control_node-1] #16   Object "", at 0xffffffffffffffff, in 
[ros2_control_node-1] #15   Object "/opt/ros/rolling/lib/controller_manager/ros2_control_node", at 0x643978079dc4, in _start
[static_transform_publisher-3] [INFO] [1713792851.178063268] [static_transform_publisher0]: Spinning until stopped - publishing transform
[static_transform_publisher-3] translation: ('0.000000', '0.000000', '0.000000')
[static_transform_publisher-3] rotation: ('0.000000', '0.000000', '0.000000', '1.000000')
[static_transform_publisher-3] from 'world' to 'base_link'
[robot_state_publisher-2] [INFO] [1713792851.179941851] [robot_state_publisher]: Robot initialized
[rviz2-4] Warning: Ignoring XDG_SESSION_TYPE=wayland on Gnome. Use QT_QPA_PLATFORM=wayland to run on Wayland anyway.
[move_group-5] [INFO] [1713792851.211702117] [move_group.moveit.RDFLoader]: Loaded robot model in 0.00301185 seconds
[move_group-5] [INFO] [1713792851.211849546] [move_group.moveit.robot_model]: Loading robot model 'rm_robot'...
[ros2_control_node-1] #14   Source "../csu/libc-start.c", line 392, in __libc_start_main_impl [0x7c536b229e3f]
[ros2_control_node-1] #13   Source "../sysdeps/nptl/libc_start_call_main.h", line 58, in __libc_start_call_main [0x7c536b229d8f]
[ros2_control_node-1] #12   Object "/opt/ros/rolling/lib/controller_manager/ros2_control_node", at 0x643978079872, in main
[ros2_control_node-1] #11   Object "/opt/ros/rolling/lib/libcontroller_manager.so", at 0x7c536be3c13a, in controller_manager::ControllerManager::ControllerManager(std::shared_ptr<rclcpp::Executor>, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, rclcpp::NodeOptions const&)
[ros2_control_node-1] #10   Object "/opt/ros/rolling/lib/libcontroller_manager.so", at 0x7c536be3f9e6, in controller_manager::ControllerManager::init_resource_manager(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&)
[ros2_control_node-1] #9    Object "/opt/ros/rolling/lib/libhardware_interface.so", at 0x7c536b9bad80, in hardware_interface::ResourceManager::load_urdf(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, bool, bool)
[ros2_control_node-1] #8    Object "/opt/ros/rolling/lib/libhardware_interface.so", at 0x7c536b9b8d50, in 
[ros2_control_node-1] #7    Object "/opt/ros/rolling/lib/libhardware_interface.so", at 0x7c536b9997e4, in 
[ros2_control_node-1] #6    Object "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.30", at 0x7c536b6ae4d7, in __cxa_throw
[ros2_control_node-1] #5    Object "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.30", at 0x7c536b6ae276, in std::terminate()
[ros2_control_node-1] #4    Object "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.30", at 0x7c536b6ae20b, in 
[ros2_control_node-1] #3    Object "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.30", at 0x7c536b6a2b9d, in 
[ros2_control_node-1] #2    Source "./stdlib/abort.c", line 79, in abort [0x7c536b2287f2]
[ros2_control_node-1] #1    Source "../sysdeps/posix/raise.c", line 26, in raise [0x7c536b242475]
[ros2_control_node-1] #0  | Source "./nptl/pthread_kill.c", line 89, in __pthread_kill_internal
[ros2_control_node-1]     | Source "./nptl/pthread_kill.c", line 78, in __pthread_kill_implementation
[ros2_control_node-1]       Source "./nptl/pthread_kill.c", line 44, in __pthread_kill [0x7c536b2969fc]
[ros2_control_node-1] Aborted (Signal sent by tkill() 54645 1000)
[move_group-5] [INFO] [1713792851.257218381] [move_group.moveit.kdl_kinematics_plugin]: Joint weights for group 'robot_arm': 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
[move_group-5] [INFO] [1713792851.395798423] [move_group.moveit.planning_scene_monitor]: Publishing maintained planning scene on 'monitored_planning_scene'
[move_group-5] [INFO] [1713792851.396015480] [move_group.moveit.moveit_cpp]: Listening to 'joint_states' for joint states
[move_group-5] [INFO] [1713792851.396442961] [move_group.moveit.current_state_monitor]: Listening to joint states on topic 'joint_states'
[move_group-5] [INFO] [1713792851.396822952] [move_group.moveit.planning_scene_monitor]: Listening to '/attached_collision_object' for attached collision objects
[move_group-5] [INFO] [1713792851.396846837] [move_group.moveit.planning_scene_monitor]: Starting planning scene monitor
[move_group-5] [INFO] [1713792851.397440463] [move_group.moveit.planning_scene_monitor]: Listening to '/planning_scene'
[move_group-5] [INFO] [1713792851.397461764] [move_group.moveit.planning_scene_monitor]: Starting world geometry update monitor for collision objects, attached objects, octomap updates.
[move_group-5] [INFO] [1713792851.397727219] [move_group.moveit.planning_scene_monitor]: Listening to 'collision_object'
[move_group-5] [INFO] [1713792851.398052108] [move_group.moveit.planning_scene_monitor]: Listening to 'planning_scene_world' for planning scene world geometry
[move_group-5] [WARN] [1713792851.398229427] [move_group.moveit.occupancy_map_monitor]: Resolution not specified for Octomap. Assuming resolution = 0.1 instead
[move_group-5] [ERROR] [1713792851.398250309] [move_group.moveit.occupancy_map_monitor]: No 3D sensor plugin(s) defined for octomap updates
[move_group-5] terminate called after throwing an instance of 'rclcpp::ParameterTypeException'
[move_group-5]   what():  expected [string_array] got [string]
[move_group-5] Stack trace (most recent call last):
[move_group-5] #17   Object "", at 0xffffffffffffffff, in 
[move_group-5] #16   Object "/opt/ros/rolling/lib/moveit_ros_move_group/move_group", at 0x6497b94abd24, in _start
[move_group-5] #15   Source "../csu/libc-start.c", line 392, in __libc_start_main_impl [0x702317029e3f]
[move_group-5] #14   Source "../sysdeps/nptl/libc_start_call_main.h", line 58, in __libc_start_call_main [0x702317029d8f]
[move_group-5] #13   Object "/opt/ros/rolling/lib/moveit_ros_move_group/move_group", at 0x6497b94aa48c, in main
[move_group-5] #12   Object "/opt/ros/rolling/lib/libmoveit_cpp.so.2.9.0", at 0x702317d1af7f, in moveit_cpp::MoveItCpp::MoveItCpp(std::shared_ptr<rclcpp::Node> const&, moveit_cpp::MoveItCpp::Options const&)
[move_group-5] #11   Object "/opt/ros/rolling/lib/libmoveit_cpp.so.2.9.0", at 0x702317d17820, in moveit_cpp::MoveItCpp::loadPlanningPipelines(moveit_cpp::MoveItCpp::PlanningPipelineOptions const&)
[move_group-5] #10   Object "/opt/ros/rolling/lib/libmoveit_planning_pipeline_interfaces.so.2.9.0", at 0x7023173c743c, in moveit::planning_pipeline_interfaces::createPlanningPipelineMap(std::vector<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::allocator<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > > > const&, std::shared_ptr<moveit::core::RobotModel const> const&, std::shared_ptr<rclcpp::Node> const&, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&)
[move_group-5] #9    Object "/opt/ros/rolling/lib/libmoveit_planning_pipeline.so.2.9.0", at 0x70231729d115, in planning_pipeline::PlanningPipeline::PlanningPipeline(std::shared_ptr<moveit::core::RobotModel const> const&, std::shared_ptr<rclcpp::Node> const&, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&)
[move_group-5] #8    Object "/opt/ros/rolling/lib/libmoveit_planning_pipeline.so.2.9.0", at 0x702317298ccf, in 
[move_group-5] #7    Object "/opt/ros/rolling/lib/librclcpp.so", at 0x7023178de8ed, in 
[move_group-5] #6    Object "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.30", at 0x7023174ae4d7, in __cxa_throw
[move_group-5] #5    Object "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.30", at 0x7023174ae276, in std::terminate()
[move_group-5] #4    Object "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.30", at 0x7023174ae20b, in 
[move_group-5] #3    Object "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.30", at 0x7023174a2b9d, in 
[move_group-5] #2    Source "./stdlib/abort.c", line 79, in abort [0x7023170287f2]
[move_group-5] #1    Source "../sysdeps/posix/raise.c", line 26, in raise [0x702317042475]
[move_group-5] #0  | Source "./nptl/pthread_kill.c", line 89, in __pthread_kill_internal
[move_group-5]     | Source "./nptl/pthread_kill.c", line 78, in __pthread_kill_implementation
[move_group-5]       Source "./nptl/pthread_kill.c", line 44, in __pthread_kill [0x7023170969fc]
[move_group-5] Aborted (Signal sent by tkill() 54653 1000)
[rviz2-4] [INFO] [1713792851.593064503] [rviz2]: Stereo is NOT SUPPORTED
[rviz2-4] [INFO] [1713792851.593154106] [rviz2]: OpenGl version: 4.6 (GLSL 4.6)
[rviz2-4] [INFO] [1713792851.623331485] [rviz2]: Stereo is NOT SUPPORTED
[rviz2-4] Warning: class_loader.impl: SEVERE WARNING!!! A namespace collision has occurred with plugin factory for class rviz_default_plugins::displays::InteractiveMarkerDisplay. New factory will OVERWRITE existing one. This situation occurs when libraries containing plugins are directly linked against an executable (the one running right now generating this message). Please separate plugins out into their own library or just don't link against the library and use either class_loader::ClassLoader/MultiLibraryClassLoader to open.
[rviz2-4]          at line 321 in /opt/ros/rolling/include/class_loader/class_loader/class_loader_core.hpp
[ERROR] [ros2_control_node-1]: process has died [pid 54645, exit code -6, cmd '/opt/ros/rolling/lib/controller_manager/ros2_control_node --ros-args --params-file /tmp/launch_params_ydvvefor --params-file /home/robot/laba_robots/install/rm75_6f/share/rm75_6f/config/ros2_controllers.yaml'].
[ERROR] [move_group-5]: process has died [pid 54653, exit code -6, cmd '/opt/ros/rolling/lib/moveit_ros_move_group/move_group --ros-args --params-file /tmp/launch_params_r48oi9nl'].
[ros2 run controller_manager spawner joint_state_controller-7] [INFO] [1713792853.670312631] [spawner_joint_state_controller]: Waiting for '/controller_manager' node to exist
[ros2 run controller_manager spawner robot_arm_controller-6] [INFO] [1713792853.690777864] [spawner_robot_arm_controller]: Waiting for '/controller_manager' node to exist
[rviz2-4] [ERROR] [1713792854.748270515] [moveit_3965937123.motion_planning_frame]: Action server: /recognize_objects not available
[rviz2-4] [INFO] [1713792854.770000661] [moveit_3965937123.motion_planning_frame]: MoveGroup namespace changed: / -> . Reloading params.
[ros2 run controller_manager spawner joint_state_controller-7] [INFO] [1713792855.685316523] [spawner_joint_state_controller]: Waiting for '/controller_manager' node to exist
[ros2 run controller_manager spawner robot_arm_controller-6] [INFO] [1713792855.705372084] [spawner_robot_arm_controller]: Waiting for '/controller_manager' node to exist
[ros2 run controller_manager spawner joint_state_controller-7] [INFO] [1713792857.700297160] [spawner_joint_state_controller]: Waiting for '/controller_manager' node to exist
[ros2 run controller_manager spawner robot_arm_controller-6] [INFO] [1713792857.719742542] [spawner_robot_arm_controller]: Waiting for '/controller_manager' node to exist
[ros2 run controller_manager spawner joint_state_controller-7] [INFO] [1713792859.715048237] [spawner_joint_state_controller]: Waiting for '/controller_manager' node to exist
[ros2 run controller_manager spawner robot_arm_controller-6] [INFO] [1713792859.735362340] [spawner_robot_arm_controller]: Waiting for '/controller_manager' node to exist
[ros2 run controller_manager spawner joint_state_controller-7] [ERROR] [1713792861.730129929] [spawner_joint_state_controller]: Controller manager not available
[ros2 run controller_manager spawner robot_arm_controller-6] [ERROR] [1713792861.749942173] [spawner_robot_arm_controller]: Controller manager not available
[ros2 run controller_manager spawner joint_state_controller-7] [ros2run]: Process exited with failure 1
[ros2 run controller_manager spawner robot_arm_controller-6] [ros2run]: Process exited with failure 1
[ERROR] [ros2 run controller_manager spawner joint_state_controller-7]: process has died [pid 54657, exit code 1, cmd 'ros2 run controller_manager spawner joint_state_controller'].
[ERROR] [ros2 run controller_manager spawner robot_arm_controller-6]: process has died [pid 54655, exit code 1, cmd 'ros2 run controller_manager spawner robot_arm_controller'].
[rviz2-4] [ERROR] [1713792865.855208577] [rviz]: Could not find parameter robot_description_semantic and did not receive robot_description_semantic via std_msgs::msg::String subscription within 10.000000 seconds.
[rviz2-4] Error:   Could not parse the SRDF XML File. Error=XML_ERROR_EMPTY_DOCUMENT ErrorID=13 (0xd) Line number=0
[rviz2-4]          at line 715 in ./src/model.cpp
[rviz2-4] [ERROR] [1713792865.858957991] [moveit_3965937123.RDFLoader]: Unable to parse SRDF
[rviz2-4] [ERROR] [1713792865.869229403] [moveit_3965937123.planning_scene_monitor]: Robot model not loaded

I have 2 projects - both work fine on ROS2 Rolling installed last year, and both don't work at newly installed ROS2 Rolling. Errors looks similar.
Please help me to understand and solve the problem.
Files tree:


Please read the console output carefully
[ros2_control_node-1]   what():  According to the loaded plugin descriptions the class fake_components/GenericSystem with base class type hardware_interface::SystemInterface does not exist. Declared types are  mock_components/GenericSystem test_hardware_components/TestSystemCommandModes test_hardware_components/TestTwoJointSystem

The hardware component was renamed two years ago, you probably ignored the deprecation warning every time. In the meantime, fake_components was removed completely. Adapt your ros2_control XML file by replacing fake_components/GenericSystem with mock_components/GenericSystem and everything should work fine.

Thanks a lot. It helps, but not completely.

Controllers was loaded, but I still has errors related to move_group, which I fixed by following this https://github.com/ros-planning/moveit2/blob/1fb4041e690c64b847d2df1e844c8de148796c86/MIGRATION.md Now it's working!

Great. Please mark the answer to flag this question as answered.
